# weird test syntax in lambda expression : x in {"key1", "key2"}

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dictionary, lambda

I'm pretty new to python (a few months), so excuse my ignorance...

During the compilation of opencv, the compilation failed on SyntaxError on this line:

`has_mat = len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in {"Mat", "vector_Mat"}, args))) > 0`

```
                                                  ^
```

I have never seen this syntax ... (not the lambda expression, the x in {"key1", "key2"} part). As far as I understand this part, it should have been written:

```
has_mat = len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in ["Mat", "vector_Mat"], args))) > 0
```

or

```
has_mat = len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in {"Mat":1, "vector_Mat":1}, args))) > 0
```

So just for my personnal culture, could someone explain what does this mean ? and which alternative syntax could I use if my python version doesn't support this one ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's a `set` not a `dict`, also not sure why it should've failed as it looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing here, `{"Mat":1, "vector_Mat":1}` is a Python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set). `set`s can be created by passing an iterable to `set()` or with a set literal as can be seen in your example. `set` is a Python type that contains only unique values:

```
In [1]: set([1, 1, 2, 3])
Out[1]: {1, 2, 3}
```

`set` also supports a number of useful comparison operations which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set).